# python MySQL dose not save to my database table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

```
import MySQL. Connector

db2 = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", port="3306", user="root", database="DB9db");
db2cursor=db2.cursor()

#sql="INSERT INTO novatable3 (Nid,Namee,Gender,Age,Qualification,DoB) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
#var=("33","summeya","F","17","bsc","2005")

sql="INSERT INTO chktbl (name, salary) values (%s, %s)"
var=[("summeya",33),("summeya",33),("summeya",33),("summeya",33),("summeya",33),("summeya",33),("summeya",33),("summeya",33)]
db2cursor.executemany(sql, var)
#

print(db2cursor.rowcount,"records insertd")
db2cursor.commit()
```

the `commit()` dose not save any data to my apache MySQL database. in python code MySQL-connecter

Comment: What does it say in the `records inserted` print?

Comment: @nbk You mean the one that's commented out?

Comment: You don't need a commit after each insert. When you commit it saves all the pending changes.

Comment: you should try the code in mysql directly, this should work, if you don#t have any unique restrainta, that prevents multiple inserts of the same data, of youzrse you could have a foreign key restraint, and "summeya" doesn't exisst.

Answer (score 0):

In the code, you have called the `commit()` method on the cursor object, but you should call it on the database connection object instead.